# Cakephp custom query with joining the same table to convert to the cakephp standard

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I am making a custom query as below for the messaging system

```
SELECT m1.mid, 
    users.id AS userid, users.name, users.lname 
    FROM
    chat_messages AS m1,
    chat_messages AS m2,
    users
    WHERE (
             (
                m1.user1 = "' . $logged_user . '"
                AND users.id = m1.user2
                AND m1.user1alldel = "0"
                AND m1.user1allarchive = "0"
             )
             OR (
                m1.user2 = "' . $logged_user . '"
                AND users.id = m1.user1
                AND m1.user2alldel = "0"
                AND m1.user2allarchive = "0"
                )
          )
          AND m1.mid2 = "1"
          AND m2.mid = m1.mid
    GROUP BY m1.mid
    ORDER BY m1.modified DESC
```

Can anyone please help me in how to use this query in cakephp custom pagination or in a general find query.

I am stuck with client and this needs to be done fast. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the CakePHP official documentation. It has all you need to know about find and joining tables.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0):

For **CUSTOM QUERY PAGINATION** 
You have add your own find method, for example: **chatUsers** in Your **User model** like:

```
public $findMethods = array(
        'chatUsers' => true,
    );
```

Then create/delare (in the same model - User model) Your own method/function **_findChatUsers**

```
protected function _findChatUsers($state, $query, $results = array()) {
        if ($state === 'before') {
                // debug($query); die(); // to see Your query
                // ... modify Your query

           return $query;
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

Read more about CakePHP find $params: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find
Then **modify Your query** like:

```
$query['fields'] = array('User.id', 'User.lname', '...');
$query['joins'] = array('INNER JOIN chat_messages AS m1...');
$query['conditons'] = array('User.id' => '...');
$query['group'] = array('User.id');
$query['order'] = array('User.id' => 'ASC');
```

or faster way:

```
        $options = array(
            'fields' => array('...'),
            'joins' => array('...'),
            // ...
        );
        $query = Set::merge($query, $options);
```

More about [SET::functions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html)
... and finally, in Your **controller** (UsersController.php), retrieve Your data like:

```
$this->paginate = array('chatUsers',
    'limit' => 6,
);
$posts = $this->paginate($this->User);
$this->set('posts', $posts);
```